# iOS saving a bunch of UIImages and restore at later stage

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I have a canvas that contains a bunch of UIImageViews and they editable, individually movable and stretchable.

Now, I like to save the state of that and close my app and at later times I like bring the canvas back up and still contain the movable UIImageViews like before.

I cannot save everything as .png file to my NSDocument directory because if I do that, later I try to restore that it will bring back as a whole png file, no more individaully moveable UIImageviews.

So, how do I save it and still retain the individually movable and editable canvas?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a handle to all the UIImageView subviews, why not take the raw images from them (e.g. "`myImageView.image`") and save the JPEG representation from them (via the [UIImageJPEGRepresentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/UIImageJPEGRepresentation) method) somewhere where each image can be restored from later on?

If they've been stretched, you could save the "state" of the saved images as well (so that when the files are restored at launch time, the app will know how the user had them last displayed).

Comment: can u show an example of the state you talking about? Position on canvas, stretched size, rotation, angle...etc.   So basically you recommend saving each UIImageView indiviudally.

Comment: I'll counter that with a question of my own: when you stretch or turn or rotate your UIImageViews, does the image data underneath get modified at all?

Comment: The base canvas which is just another UIImageview. The invidual smaller  UIImageViews would lay top of that. So, when you stretched those top UIImageViews the bottom canvas shouldn't change.